# Woocommerce Remove Tax by Product Type

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am customizing a Woocommerce install under the following parameters.

1. The website sells precious metals as well as other types of items. The state which the business resides does not charge tax on precious metals if the total amount of precious metal sale is at least $500.
2. Tax still has to be charged on all other items as well as metal sales below $500.

(The website can sell 1 silver coin for $20 at it needs to be taxed, however if someone purchases 25 coins at $20 then no tax is charged on the coins.)

Additionally, I wrote a some code for bulk pricing which works fine, however is slightly tied into removing tax.

The issue I am having is when I remove the tax from the item, the cart does not seem to recalculate the tax.

Here is my code:

This function works great for my bulk pricing functionality and determining whether or not to remove taxes.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_edit_product_price_at_cart');

function woo_edit_product_price_at_cart($cart)
{
   $cart_totals = [];

   foreach($cart->cart_contents as $item):

   if('metal'===get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_product_type', 1)):               
       array_push($cart_totals, $item['line_total']);            
       $item['data']->price = agspp_get_price_in_range($item['quantity'], get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_bulk_pricing', 1));
       endif;
    endforeach;            

    if(array_sum($cart_totals) >= 500):
       $_SESSION['_agspp_remove_tax'] = true;
       return;
   endif;

   $_SESSION['_agspp_remove_tax'] = false;        
}
```

However, actually trying to remove tax is where the issue is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'woo_remove_item_tax',9999);
function woo_remove_item_tax($cart)
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['_agspp_remove_tax']) ||   !$_SESSION['_agspp_remove_tax']):
       return;
   endif;

   foreach($cart->cart_contents as $item):

       if('metal'===get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_product_type', 1)):
           $item['line_tax'] = 0;
           $item['line_subtotal_tax'] = 0;
           $item['line_tax_data'] = [];

       endif;            

   endforeach;
}
```

The function actually removes the taxes from the item object, however, cannot seem to get the cart to recalculate the taxes.

How can I do this?

Thaks

Answer (score 1):

After many headaches and trials and errors, instead of trying to recalculate the taxes, I just altered the taxes.

I changed my foreach loop in the second function to the following:

```
if('metal'===get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_product_type', 1)):               
    $cart->taxes[1] -= $item['line_tax'];
    $cart->tax_total -= $item['line_tax'];
    $item['line_tax'] = 0;
    $item['line_subtotal_tax'] = 0;
    $item['line_tax_data'] = [];
    $cart->cart_contents[$key] = $item;
endif;
```

Now it works like I need it too. Yippee!!!